# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:NBioBSPJNI.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, awt, executable-jar

I have two jar files. I expand the jar files
lookup in to the native library i put the 32 bit dll. System configuration is 64 bit & i am using 32 bit jre and 32 bit dll.

I am getting error. Itries System.loadlibrary & vm arguments....